# Loading js file via jQuery $ajax in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, loading

I'm suffering problems with the next code in IE, in Chrome, Safari and FF is working properly, how can I fix it?

```
function loadCrop() {
  $.ajax({
   url: baseurl+'public/default/js/users/crop.js',
   dataType: "script",
   success: isReady,
   error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert('error: '+textStatus+' - '+errorThrown);
  }
 });
}
```

it shows the alert:
error: parsererror - 
Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101

Thanks!

Comment: it shows the alert error: parsererror - Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101

Comment: http://mattwhite.me/blog/2010/4/21/tracking-down-error-80020101-in-internet-exploder.html Please refer this! also do you have any comments in your js file? if yes then use /*Comment*/ instead of //comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error 80020101 means is that there is an error, of some sort, when evaluating JavaScript. If you load that JavaScript via Ajax.

You can track it using. http://mattwhite.me/blog/2010/4/21/tracking-down-error-80020101-in-internet-exploder.html

First try to debug and load js file directly. check what error you get

Comment: there are not problems, not comments... this is the js that Im loading: http://pastebin.com/44xKuFYL